# Powershell getting values via regex

Tags: regex, powershell

Normally , I can catch values beginning with `Windows Server` like below script. But I want to get version number for operating systems as well.

```
Windows Embedded
Windows XP
Windows 7  
Windows 10
Windows Server® 2008 Standard
Windows Server® 2008 Enterprise
```

So , it will be only `7` ,`XP` , `10` , `Embedded` , `2008` inside `version` variable.

Script :

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$computer'" -Properties OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$version = ([regex]'Windows Server (\d+)').Match($server.OperatingSystem).Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: There is an `®` symbol, try `Windows Server\D+(\w+)` to match it and spaces, too. `\w` will match letters and digits (and `_`, too).

Comment: You could also try `Windows(?: Server)?[^\w\r\n]+(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/iRhmJT/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This match every line and capture exactly what you want :

```
Windows(?: Server)?[^\w\r\n]+(\w+).*
```

Comment: That is an awesome solution! :-) Note that just to get the value in the group, you can omit `.*`

Comment: I was wondering if PowerShell would still match the line without the `.*`, thank you for this precision ! :)